# New relic not displaing api name for metrics only showing serviceExceute as endpoint

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

New relic not displaying api name for metrics only showing serviceExceute as endpoint.I checked the new relic config nothing seems to be a miss in general in profile.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7hYx.png)

Checked the config with other services where this is working but didn't saw any difference in the config file,